# Shifting HTML content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to ask a query which most find very easier. I'm making use of jQuery to apply CSS for margin-left or padding as:

```
margin: 0px 0px 0px 156px
```

I have a requirement to shift all the dynamic content upto a particular pixel value of the window. (I have a calculated value out of the Window size say 160px)
The dynamic content will contain the properties as:

```
padding-left: 2px;
text-align: right;
font-size: 91%;
font-weight: bold;
```

**Problem:** If the content contains 1 letter (say 'A') it needs to be at 156px from left, thereafter I see if another letter say 'B' comes it requires another 8 pixels so the left shift requires to have 148 pixels. But if the content comes in small letters then again its harder to say what number of pixel value should be provided to fit the requirement. Also, if I place 'I' letter then it takes around 4 pixels.

The above doesn't seem to be feasible as different characters have different spacing associated.

I need to achieve the dynamic content to be placed 160px from left all aligned (along with the imaginary 160px from left).

Can you let me know if it can be done via CSS if not then jQuery or Java Script?

**Edit:**

Some HTML content:

I want the alignment to come over my main page containing an iFrame content as follows:

```
<iframe 
    frameborder="no" 
    height="200px" 
    id="06690000002ravz" 
    marginheight="0" 
    marginwidth="0" 
    name="06690000002ravz" 
    scrolling="no" 
    title="Rule1" 
    width="100%">

    <label id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id3:theField" class="labelCol">
        abcX
    </label>

</iframe>
```

The **abcX** is the dynamic content I'm receiving over the main page.

Every time I receive this the content should get automatically aligned.

PS: There is no communication between them (as they are not from the same domain). Means, I'm unable to obtain the document.parent.getElementById to obtain any outer element or size of window etc.

Comment: Could you please post the code you have so far.

Comment: It can be done with the help of JavaScript and CSS. You can check the browser.width or window.width and then according to that shift the CSS! For this you might need to write the CSS in the Head tag not in the site.css file! Or what ever the file you are using.

Comment: The HTML code is generated from the library we are using (Apex), the fragment of the code we want to align comes under an iFrame and we are setting the alignment from within the iFrame itself. Should we look for the whole window or from within iFrame ?

Comment: We are also getting the sloppy behavior that whenever we re-size for the browser window the alignment doesn't come right. (Do we need to maintain some kind of positioning like relative, fixed or absolute? )

Comment: I find it very hard to decipher what exactly you want and what currently is happening. Could you copy a minimal amount of html (and corresponding css) that shows the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry for this. I have made some edits. Please let me know if it needs to be still modified or added some extra information.

Comment: Unless you articulate your question better, it's difficult to help you. The problem with that is that you have seen the problem, and we're trying to see it from your words. Difficult, very difficult.

Comment: Yep - another vote for "put the code on jsfiddle so we have a better idea how to help you."

Comment: Perhaps a picture would be helpful for illustrating what you want.